# How to use a PROMPT_COMMAND inside a function

Tags: bash, terminal, centos7

I don't have a lot of experience with Bash as such. I will be working with multiple terminals in a single desktop and hence thought it might be a good idea to label my terminals so that I know what is running where.

I am running CentOS 7 and the default terminal that comes as a part of the OS [does not support](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=740188) direct modification of Terminal Label and hence I have been modifying it by using the following command:

> PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;**TITLE GOES HERE**\007”’

I found this piece of code on the internet and this command works perfectly fine. It does what I want it to. However, since I am using multiple terminals, I thought it might be a good idea to put this inside a custom function and source that file so that I can use with a variable name.

So this is what I did.

```
termName(){
    PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;$1\007”’
}
```

I put the above code inside a file called ".aliases" located in my home directory and sourced it. I then wrote:

> termName ABC

However, nothing happens. Instead, my terminal gets renamed as Terminal. Can someone point where I am going wrong?

PS: I did put "source ~/.aliases" inside by .bashrc file so I do know that the file is sourced for every terminal that I open.

Answer (score 3):

`PROMPT_COMMAND` is just the variable that holds pieces of code that should run each time your prompt is displayed. The code that actually changes your terminal is the `echo` command, which is all you need in your `termName` function.

```
termName () {
    echo -ne "\033]0;$1\007"
}
```

A slightly cleaner definition would use `printf` instead:

```
termName () {
  printf '\033]0;%s\007' "$1"
}
```

Add that definition to the standard `.bashrc` file to ensure it is defined in any interactive `bash` session you start.

Comment: I tried this. It does not work. It again changes the terminal title to simply Terminal and not ABC. Tried both types.

Comment: And moreover, the PROMPT_COMMAND needs to be a part otherwise the relabeling will not work. I think the PROMPT_COMMAND is an internal variable that needs to be modified.

Comment: The function works (or at least, it does after I restored the semicolon I forgot in the `printf` version), but you appear to have code in your `PROMPT_COMMAND` overwrites whatever change `termName` makes.

Comment: Can I know what terminal are you using? Cause I tried this (the 'printf') in the default gnome-terminal that comes along with Centos 7 and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not getting the escape sequences right? Also, how about trying to modify PS1 from within PROMPT_COMMAND instead?

Comment: Not really. The code works when I directly apply it to the terminal. And this has nothing to do with PS1 from what I know. PS1 is for changing the terminal handle name inside the terminal. I am talking about the terminal label that appears on the top of the terminal above the menu bar

Comment: But there is a sequence that you can put into PS1 for changing the terminal title. Maybe this depends on support from the terminal.